# node-java typescript import

Tags: node.js, typescript

I need to use [node-java](https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-java) node_module in my typescript project.

However,

```
var java = require("java");
```

does not work in typescript way, and also

```
import java = module("java");
```

does not work as it is.

I know we may need a definition file etc. and there's a project like
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Having said that, I think it's way too complicated to do by myself.

Is there any easier workaround? Thanks.

Comment: What are you using as module loader? RequireJS?

Comment: @Anzeo node.js has a built-in module loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is use a definition file to `node-java` API, however, using your first code snippet:

```
var java = require("java");
```

you can use a reference to [this node typing](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts) as following:

```
/// <reference path="node/node.d.ts" />

var java = require("java");

java.classpath.push("commons-lang3-3.1.jar");
java.classpath.push("commons-io.jar");

var list = java.newInstanceSync("java.util.ArrayList");

java.newInstance("java.util.ArrayList", function(err, list) {
  list.addSync("item1");
  list.addSync("item2");
});

var ArrayList = java.import('java.util.ArrayList');
var list2 = new ArrayList();
list.addSync('item1');
```

To use the second snippet:

```
import java = module("java");
```

you will need a definition file. To a kick start you can create a `node-java.d.ts` file with the following code:

```
module "java" {
    export var classpath: { push(jar: string); };
    export function newInstanceSync(type: string);
    export function newInstance(type: string, callback: (err, list) => any);
    export function import(type: string);
    export function newArray(...item: any[]);
    export function callStaticMethodSync(...args: any[]);
}
```

And use this file as following:

```
/// <reference path="node-java.d.ts" />

import java = module("java");

java.classpath.push("commons-lang3-3.1.jar");
java.classpath.push("commons-io.jar");

var list = java.newInstanceSync("java.util.ArrayList");

java.newInstance("java.util.ArrayList", function(err, list) {
  list.addSync("item1");
  list.addSync("item2");
});

var ArrayList = java.import('java.util.ArrayList');
var list2 = new ArrayList();
list.addSync('item1');
```

Having time, I'll send a `node-java` definition to [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) repository.

Comment: Diullei, thanks for very helpful tutorial. I am going to implement your suggestion. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that this doesn't work:

```
var java = require("java");
```

I'm assuming you get an error directly calling `require` because it doesn't have type information.

One way to solve this is to add type information for require:

```
declare var require: (module: string) => any;
var java = require('java');
```

This is a simplistic example - `java` won't be typed as the return value of `require` in my example is `any` - but if you had type information you could cast it:

```
declare var require: (module: string) => any;
var java = <JavaDefinition> require('java');
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve. Actually, your suggestion for -declare/require method is the one I was looking for, and very informative.